# PHP syntax issue -- if statement followed by foreach loop

Tags: php, joomla

I am having some trouble with a syntax issue, can someone help me identify the problem?  It's an if statement followed by a foreach loop:

```
$start_date = strtotime('2006-01-01');
$end_date = strtotime('2006-12-31');

if ($item->date >= $start_date && <= $end_date) {

foreach (expression) { 
     statement;
}
```

I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL for:

```
if ($item->date >= $start_date && <= $end_date) {
```

Thoughts, suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: While @lxg is correct, to make it easier on you, I'd also recommend using parenthesis...it becomes a little clearer that way - `if( ($item->date >= $start_date) && ($item->date <= $end_date)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
if ($item->date >= $start_date && $item->date <= $end_date) {
// …
```

Otherwise, the second condition is incomplete.